# 2 entries in one channel

Tags: channel-entries, count

I am pretty new to exsprexxion engine and want to ask a quistion i want to do this:

```
<ul class="touchcarousel-container">
  <li class="touchcarousel-item">
    <div class="rblock"> ITEM 1 </div> 
    <div class="balk_wit"></div>  
    <div class="rblock"> ITEM 2 </div>
  </li>  
  <li class="touchcarousel-item">   
    <div class="rblock"> ITEM 3 </div>  
    <div class="balk_wit"></div>  
    <div class="rblock"> ITEM 4 </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

ENZ....

When I try it I only get all the entries in the upper part of the `<li>` (so they all come in the place of "ITEM 1"). Is there a way to count and display only the od ones and for the bottom `<li>` the od ones?

It would be nice if you can help me out.
Leon

Ok this is the code:

```
                <div class="rblock">
                {exp:channel:entries channel="track_record" dynamic="off"}
                {if count==1}
                     <div class="balk"><p>{title}</p></div>
                    {exp:ce_img:single img src="{track_record_picture}" alt="{title}" width="230" height="132" crop="y" allow_scale_larger="yes"}
                    <div class="text"><p>{track_record_description}</p></div>


                </div>



                <div class="balk_wit"></div>

                <div class="rblock">
                {if count==2}

                    <div class="balk"><p>{title}</p></div>
                    {exp:ce_img:single img src="{track_record_picture}" alt="{title}" width="230" height="132" crop="y" allow_scale_larger="yes"}
                    <div class="text"><p>{track_record_description}</p></div>
                    {/exp:channel:entries}
                </div>
                {/if}
            </li>
```

Comment: You need to show us your current EE template code, not just what you want as the output.

Comment: Please show us more of what you currently have in your code. Do you have any EE tags `{exp:channel:entries ...}` for example?

Comment: I have submited it in the post. thnx for the tip!

Comment: `dynamic="off"` should be `dynamic="no"` though I don't think that will cure your problem completely... Also, unless I'm mistaken, your second `if` should either close the first `if` then open the second one, or the second one should be an `{if:elseif}`

Comment: thanx it's indeed dynamic="no" but the other thing with the if statement didn't work out is is still just showing 1 entrie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most simples way for this is used **switch** tag

```
<ul class="touchcarousel-container">
                {exp:channel:entries channel="track_record" dynamic="off"}
                    {switch='<li class="touchcarousel-item">|'}
                    <div class="balk"><p>{title}</p></div>
                    {exp:ce_img:single img src="{track_record_picture}" alt="{title}" width="230" height="132" crop="y" allow_scale_larger="yes"}
                    <div class="text"><p>{track_record_description}</p></div>
                    {switch='<div class="balk_wit"></div>|</li>'}
                {/exp:channel:entries}
</ul>
```

Comment: This works out fine! thanx Max!